# GET the OS password in the customer portal with API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to get OS password written in the portal and construct the provisioning script which enable us to reboot and login during the script procedure.

Where can we get such a information?
Hopefully we may be able to get from the link like 
https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata/Datacenter

Can we get OS password like this?
https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata/Datacenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata service is not possible.

You can use the SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata to get the id of the virtual guest or bare metal, calling this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata/getId e.g.

```
GET https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata/getId
```

It will return the id of the Virtual Guest or of the bare metal server, then you need to use the [Softlayer_Virtual_Guest::getOperatingSystem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getOperatingSystem) or [Softlyer_Hardware_Server::getOperatingSystem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getOperatingSystem) methods (but those methods meeds authentication)

e.g.

```
GET https://$USERANME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/VSIID/getOperatingSystem?objectMask=mask[passwords]
```

Regards